# Single char not printing. x86-32 intel assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit

I am trying to print a single byte from my buffer into stdout, but I am not getting any output, I have looked up how to print a single byte, and it IS in fact getting stored/moved as expected (Used gdb to debug). the byte even gets saved to `ecx` at the end but there isn't any output. What could be the issue?
I am new to assembly and have been banging my head for several hours now. Thank you for the help.

`

```
global _start

section .data
    buffer: times 100 db 0

section .start
_start:
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, buffer                ; Enter input, example: 12345
    mov edx, 10
    int 80h

    movzx esi, byte [buffer+1]     ; Extract one byte from the input buffer: Successful
    push esi                       ; Byte is successfully pushed

print:
    pop edi                        ; Byte gets successfully popped

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, edi                   ; Here's the issue, it gets saved to ecx but no output
    mov edx, 15
    int 80h

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

`
As is aid, if i input "12345"
the byte "2" (or 0x32) IS getting pushed/popped/moved correctly, it's just not printing
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mov ecx, edi                   ; Here's the issue`
Exactly.
Function `sys_write` expects `ecx` to **point** at the string but you loaded `ecx=0x00000032` which doesn't point anywhere.

Replace `mov ecx, edi` with `mov ecx, buffer+1` and `mov edx, 15` with `mov edx,1` to print just one character.